# Using environment variables within a Bash script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, environment-variables, quoting

I know that there are a few questions with answers on how to do this, however I still can't seem to get my scenario to work when wrapping my variable in double quotes.

I am executing a curl request to obtain a valid crumb in Jenkins so that I can then execute a job via a POST request.

So at the moment I get response like `Password Invalid` as the variable `${USER_TOKEN}` is not recognised

```
echo "The USER TOKEN is " ${USER_TOKEN} # This outputs 123456789 for example
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://jenkins:${USER_TOKEN}@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField, ":",//crumb)')
```

If I hardcode the `USER_TOKEN` then this will work but I obviously wanted to avoid that.

How can I execute this `curl` command and pass in the `USER_TOKEN`?

### Updates

If I surround `${USER_TOKEN}` with double quotes I still get the same error.

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://jenkins:"${USER_TOKEN}"@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField, ":",//crumb)')
```

And if I surround the `curl` request with double quotes I get

```
Invalid Xpath expression, contact(//crumbRequestField,:,//crumb)
Unexpected ':'
```

Comment: Why can't you doublequote it? `curl -s 'http://jenkins:'"${USER_TOKEN}"'@localhost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double quote a string that contains double quotes. This is one way:

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s "http://jenkins:${USER_TOKEN}@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField, "'":"'",//crumb)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s "http://jenkins:"${USER_TOKEN}"@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField, \":\",//crumb)")
```

If you want an variable expanded in your string than the whole string have to be surrounded with double quote. Single quotes prevent any bash evaluation. Also you have to escape any double quotes in the whole string.